# Server Side Events getting error

Tags: javascript, events, cfml, lucee, eventsource

So I have the following code in the javascript of the page.

```
<script>
    if (!!window.EventSource) 
        {
            var source = new EventSource('Stream.cfm');
            source.onmessage = function(event) 
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
        };
        } 
    else 
        {
    // Result to xhr polling :(
        }

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
    // Connection was opened.
    console.log('Open');
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(e);
        source.close();
    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
        // Connection was closed.
        console.log('Closed');
    }
    }, false);

</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

and on the server side, I have this..

```
<cfcontent type="text/event-stream">
data: Hello World!\n\n
```

I copied this from a few websites around the web and as I can see it, logically, this should work. However, when I run it, I get an error. It opens up correctly, but I get an error and close.

If someone can please point me to where I am going wrong, it would be very appreciated. It loads ok and it keeps refreshing... Just that I get the error and it stops there. If I take out the close, it just keeps going and keeps erroring.

If it helps any, this is running on a Lucee server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I've got laying around. Don't remember where I got the inspiration. [websocket.org](http://websocket.org) maybe?

```js
function log(x) {
 console.log(x)
}
;(function() {
 myWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
 myWebSocket.onopen = function(myEvent) { 
  $('body').append('onOpen called<br>');
  log(myEvent);
  myWebSocket.send('WebSocket rocks');
 };
 myWebSocket.onclose = function(myEvent) { 
  log(myEvent);
  $('body').append('Disconnected<br>');
 };
 myWebSocket.onmessage = function(myEvent) { 
  log(myEvent);
  $('body').append('Response: ' + myEvent.data + '<br>');
  myWebSocket.close();
 };
 myWebSocket.onerror = function(myEvent) { 
  log(myEvent);
  $('body').append('Error: ' + myEvent.data + '<br>');
 };
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```